# Are questions on government research labs on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

One definition of [academia](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Aacademia) defines it as:

> The environment or community concerned with the pursuit of research, education, and scholarship.

Whereas others would relate it more strictly to universities.  Which brings me to my question:

Are questions relating to the environment in government research laboratories on-topic?  For example, would a question like *What to expect during an interview for a research position at a government research lab in [country]?* be on-topic?  (Notwithstanding that the question is perhaps a little bit broad).

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Per the [help center](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> This site is for academics of all levels—from aspiring graduate and professional students to senior researchers — *as well as anyone in or interested in research-related or research-adjacent fields*.

That includes research in government and industry settings.

Comment: Speaking as a researcher in industry, I completely agree. :-)